# How to plot line in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a set of data points that I have plotted. I also have an equation of a line that I am supposed to plot on the same graph, in order to compare the data values to the line. I can't use a line chart because Excel gives their own equation. Is there anyway I can plot the points and somehow plot the line using my equation? And if not on Excel, where can I go to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you seed your equation with some data to get the values it outputs for each input, then plot that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to seed your equation with some data, you would produce output that you could then plot.

For example, if your equation was

```
x = y * y
```

Then using the data:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Would produce

```
1 4 9 16 25 36
```

Plotting this data is equivalent to plotting the equation.